# Is this the correct way of react hooks?

Tags: reactjs

Is meaning of const [option,setOption] = useState([])

and

const [option,setOption] = useState([null])  same??

I have written a program which is a class based component ,
I want to convert it into functional based component using react-hooks, bit got stuck!!

Let us assume if one has a number of state like ..... State={ speed:null, distance:null, acceleration:null}, then , which way is correct??

Comment: If you want to use array then this is the correct way of initializing it with an empty array:   
      const [option,setOption] = useState([])

Comment: Let us assume if one has a number of state like ..... State={ speed:null, distance:null, acceleration:null}, then , which way is correct??

Comment: Handling state with react hooks is very easy and also it is a good practice if you create multiple states with react hooks instead of one state. 
1. const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(null) 
2. const [distance, setDistance] = useState(null) 
3. const [acceleration, setAcceleration] = useState(null)

Comment: With single state: const [options, setOptions] = useState({ speed:null, distance:null, acceleration:null})